# Send Honor points via mail

Tags: command, azerothcore

Is there a way in AzerothCore to send honor points with mail using `.send items` or simillar command?

Is there maybe `.send honor` / `.send arenapoints` as an alternate approach?

I've tried to use

`.send items #playername "#subject" "#text" 43308:1000` - https://www.wowhead.com/wotlk/item=43308/honor-points

`.send items #playername "#subject" "#text" 187130:1000` - https://www.wowhead.com/wotlk/item=187130/honor-points

`.send items #playername "#subject" "#text" 187129:1000` - https://www.wowhead.com/wotlk/item=187129/honor-points

For item 43308 it does send but this currency is kind of mock. For two others it doesn't work

[image: .send items attempt]

Answer (score -1):

You can't send items 187129 and 187130 because they do not exist in patch 3.3.5a.

No command exists to send honor points by mail. You would need to program it in.